# Keyboard note setting for children

Tags: windows, gratis, music, music-composing

I am looking for a simple music note editing software which can be used by children, so

- it has very limited feature set compared to professional systems like Cubase

  - violin key only
  - 1/1, 1/2, 1/4 and 1/8 notes only
  - 3/4, 4/4, 6/4 rhythm only
  - notes from C3 to G4 (roughly)
  - no specials (fermate, repetitions, legato, staccato etc.)
  - save as MIDI file
  - no MIDI In/Out needed
- runs on Windows 7 SP1 x64
- is free / gratis / open source

It should roughly be suitable for children from 6 to 10 years.